# Ignore column order in DiffResult of Liquibase

Tags: java, sql-server, database, diff, liquibase

In the report generated by [Liquibase Core](http://www.liquibase.org/download/) (3.5.1), following this procedure:

```
DiffGeneratorFactory differencesGenerator = DiffGeneratorFactory.getInstance();
CompareControl compareControl = new CompareControl();
DiffResult comparisonResult = differencesGenerator.compare(databaseOne, databaseTwo, compareControl);
```

Liquibase is checking the order change of columns between databases:

*Diff_Output.txt*

> ```
> dbo.table_1.columnA
>  order changed from '11' to '10'
> dbo.table_1.columnB
>  order changed from '9' to '8'
> dbo.table_5.columnX
>  order changed from '14' to '11'
> ```

However I'm not interested in that kind of differences. **How can I control/supress this to be considered as a difference?** I'm only interested in knowing that all columns are there and that their names are right.

Answer (score 0):

This should be available in version 3.5.2, which I think is very close to release as of 8/28/16.